# Spring Data MongoDB: How can I find which field in Mongo Document was updated?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

We are building the `Spring Boot` Application `v2.2.8` with `Spring Data Mongo DB`,
one of the requirements that we need to cover:

- log information which `Document`s field(s) was (were) updated.

I have found that the idea of [Lifecycle Events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events) available in `Spring Data MongoDB` but I am not sure that it will help me to achieve completely my goal because there is no way to find which exactly property we are trying to update.

So, could you please advise any valid solutions or possible approaches?

Comment: Hi. I haven't used Spring Data Mongo DB specifically, but looking at MongoDB I would try something like comparing the old and the updated document after the update operation. I see no other choice. You can take a look to the command "findAndModify" of mongo which can return the modified copy of the doc: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: I even found it in the Spring Data Mongo DB docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo-template.find-and-upsert

Comment: You can take a look at MongoDB's Change Streams.